# Why is dns local cache not enabled out-of-the-box on Kubernetes?

Tags: dns, kubernetes

I remember DNS records being cached locally on various linux distros in the past, but this appears to have changed over the years ([DNS caching in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020027/dns-caching-in-linux)).

Within our environment (non-K8S) we found a noticeable delay (1-2ms) for each request due to DNS lookups because of this.

I also noticed there is no local DNS cache within K8S by default (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/45363) and the DNS cache within CoreOS is also disabled by default (https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/configuring-dns.html).

Given we're considering migrating towards K8S I was wondering; why is this not enabled for Kubernetes in particular?

My only theory is within kube-dns records are updated pre-emptively to ensure high-availability; but I'm not sure if K8S actually does that?

As a workaround, if I were to run dnsmasq on every node, would I break things? I noticed there have been attempts to make that setup the default within K8S, but those attempts/PR's appear to have gone stale and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Kubernetes 1.9+` was announced, [CoreDNS](https://coredns.io/) had been included in `kubeadm`, `minikube` tools, etc. as a default DNS server and replaced former `kube-dns` (which was based on `dnsmasq`).

It was built as a fork of the [Caddy](https://caddyserver.com/) web server and middleware chains in a way that each middleware component carries some DNS feature. If you already use `kube-dns`, it is possible to launch `CoreDNS` using this [Link](https://github.com/coredns/deployment/tree/master/kubernetes).

CoreDNS is already equipped with caching and forwarding features, assuming that caching runs as a separate component, and brokes dependency for using `dnsmasq`.

```
. {
    proxy . 8.8.8.8:53
    cache example.org
}
```

There are a lot of [plugins](https://coredns.io/plugins/) which you can use extending DNS functionality, like proxying requests, rewriting requests, doing health checks on endpoints, and publishing metrics into [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).